# How to import python module

Tags: python, module

I'm working on a project for which I need to a module.  I want to know how to import some other module in python that is not installed.

When I write

```
import xaut
```

It gives error no module named `xaut`.

I have `xaut-0.4.5` that I downloaded from following [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xautomation/?source=typ_redirect). 
Please help me how to use it.

Comment: no i am not able to install.Please guide me how to install

Comment: you have to add it to the python path, did you download/install this python module with pip or did you do it manually? Id be happy to write up an answer for how to add a python module to your python path if needed. Cheers.

Comment: how to add it to python path??I tried to run makefile using gnuwin32 but couldn't  .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think following will help

1. Extract your zip file
2. Open the command line (a linux terminal or cmd on windows). I am on linux so I have a terminal.
3. Now enter the directory that you have extracted.

   [image]
4. In it is a directory "python" cd into it.
   [image]
5. If you run the ls command (if on windows run dir) you will see that in this directory there is a script "setup.py". We need to execute it for installation.

   [image]
6. Execute this script by giving command `python setup.py install`

This will hopefully install it and then you would be able to import it.
Basically you have only downloaded the package. To make a package work you also need to install it. So when you download a package always search for a setup.py file.

Comment: I am using windows.Please give me solution for that

Comment: In my answer for step 6 type python setup.py install

Comment: error:can't copy '_xautpy.so': doesn't exist or not a regular file. This error occur when i write that command

Comment: where is it exactly?did i download the correct package?

Comment: I installed the module.But faced another problem.When i import xaut it gives following error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import xaut
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xaut.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _xautpy
ImportError: No module named _xautpy

Comment: I put the _xautpy.i also _xautpy.so file in the folder but nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

This is certainly a duplicate question. You can look up how to add a python module to the path in windows.

here is an example
[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)